Is there a concise method for shifting the integration bounds of polytopes in multidimensional integrals?
I'm looking to better understand a change of variables/u-substitution for multidimensional integrals over regions determined by polytopes.  For example, I know that
$$  \int^{1}_{0} dz \int^{1-z}_{0} dy \int^{1-z-y}_{0} dx f(x,y,z)  $$
Is the integral over a simplex and there are many methods to perform this integration analytically.  However, I seem to be having issues with an integral that has a slight change in the bounds, such as this
$$  \int^{1}_{0} dz \int^{1-z}_{0} dy \int^{z}_{0} dx f(x,y,z)  $$
The integral is still a simplex, as far as I'm understanding, however, I'd like to transform the region such that it's over the standard simplex as it is given in the first integral to ease the analytic form.  However, I can't see to determine a transformation that nicely changes the second equation into the first.  But, as far as I'm understanding, this should just be an affine shear transformation to change the bounds and then introduce the Jacobian, but every time I try to rewrite the upper integration bound of the inner most integral, it also changes the lower bound instead of keeping it at zero. Is there a nice way of doing this transformation in this case, as well as generalizing to higher dimensions?
